# How to input matrices/tables like Matlab or Python?

Tags: macros

Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but to me, writing Matrices and tables in LaTeX code is rather onerous. Would it be possible to produce an n x n matrix using a format such as Python or Matlab:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

Which should produce a square matrix with elements 1-9.

I understand tables and some matrix options would need to be specified in order for this to work, but that seems doable.

Comment: you could of course write a parser for that but if you replace space by & and ; by \\  you have the latex syntax so one extra character per row, is hardly "onerous" is it? `\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\4&5&6\\7&8&9\end{pmatrix}`

Comment: You make a compelling argument

Comment: Would PythonTeX be a reasonable choice?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302213/how-to-make-a-matrix-that-wolfram-and-symbolab-can-read-ideally-through-lyx-ds/302217#302217

Comment: You can create a script in MATLAB that from a matrix create the LaTeX syntax for the table and then save the output as a text file with extension `.tex` and then use `\input{<file>.tex}` to import in LaTeX. I have made very long tables in this way with MATHEMATICA.

Answer (score 10):

`nicematrix` is so cute...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[light-syntax]
    1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

If you want, you can even create a dedicated macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\newcommand\matlabmat[1]{%
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[light-syntax]
        #1
    \end{bNiceMatrix}%
}

\begin{document}

$\matlabmat{1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9}$

$\matlabmat{1 ; 2 ; 3 ; 4 ; 5 ; 6}$

\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are an AUCTeX/Emacs user, just active the embedded calc mode the point (cursor) on this expression (C-x * e)

```
\[A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]\]
```

instantanly the expression is converted in

```
\[A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9 \end{pmatrix} \]
```

This operation is reversible: still in calc embedded mode the command  d N does it.

Unfortunately it do not seem possible to chose the matrix environment (bmatrix for example), you have to change it `manually'.

To do so you can configure the LaTeX langage mode 2 to  display the output in two dimensional mode. C-u 2 d T do the trick. It can be

```
% [calc-mode: language: (latex 2)]
\[
A = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
    7 & 8 & 9
    \end{pmatrix}
\]
```

Don't forget to return back to latex mode (C-x * e).

To change the pmatrix into bmatrix (or whatever matrix environment you want) Just C-u C-c C-e as usual. It may be easier to do a simple find and replace.

Note that calc can perform a large number of matrix operations for numeric or symbolic values, the ability to compose in LaTeX syntax is a very basic although excellent functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the link to proposed package `nicematrix`:

https://ctan.org/pkg/nicematrix?lang=en

Comment: It is in TeX Live.