# How can I fix the alignment of the vertical dots in this matlab style syntax matrix?

Tags: matrices, nicematrix

I am trying to adapt the code from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/603879/302100) to allow for matlab style syntax for matrices in latex. In the MWE example, the alignment of the `\vdots` is incorrect (should be centered)...

[image: misalignment issues]

My MWE is...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][r]{\hskip -\arraycolsep%
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
    \array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\renewcommand\matrix[1]{%
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[r][light-syntax]
        #1
    \end{bNiceMatrix}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\matrix{\vec{x}^{(1)};\vec{x}^{(2)};\vdots;\vec{x}^{(m)}}^{T}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

How can I fix this?

*UPDATE*

I tried the solution from @F. Pantigny. It worked for `\vdots`, but for `\cdots` and `\ldots` it causes there to be extra dots between the different elements of the matrix, ie...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\renewcommand\matrix[1]{%
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[r,light-syntax,renew-dots,xdots/shorten=6pt]
        #1
    \end{bNiceMatrix}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\matrix{\vec{x}^{(1)};\vec{x}^{(2)};\vdots;\vec{x}^{(m)}}^{T} = \matrix{\vec{x}^{(1)} \vec{x}^{(2)}\cdots \vec{x}^{(n)}}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

gives...

[image: bad dots still]

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nicematrix}


\renewcommand\matrix[1]{%
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}[r,light-syntax,renew-dots,xdots/shorten=6pt]
        #1
    \end{bNiceMatrix}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\matrix{\vec{x}^{(1)};\vec{x}^{(2)};\vdots;\vec{x}^{(m)}}^{T}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you. That works to fix the alignment of the vertical dots, but for \cdots and \ldots it causes significant issues.

Comment: You should try without the key `renew-dots` but with, in the matrix, `\Vdots` (provided by `nicematrix`) instead of `\vdots`.