# How can I write a macro to convert a list into a table?

Tags: tables, loops

I think this is an easy for-loop question, but I can't seem to get it to work...

I frequently need to put a CC list at the end of the documents that I prepare. I have been making the list manually, doing something like

```
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l l}
CC: & Dr. A. Name \\
    & Mr. B. Name \\
    & Dr. C. Name 
\end{tabular}
```

How would I make a macro that accepts that list of names as an argument and outputs the tabular? I would like to declare a variable in my document

```
\cc{Dr. A Name, Mr. B Name, Dr. C Name}
```

then at the end of the doc do something like

```
\makecclist
```

which puts in the formatted cc list table at the end.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe `csvsimple` could help?

Comment: Maybe similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/620340/47927

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a breeze with `expl3`: we just need to deliver the list with `\\ &` between the items.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % uncomment if using LaTeX release prior to 2020-10-01

\ExplSyntaxOn

% declare a variable
\clist_new:N \g_userx_cc_names_clist

% populate the variable
\NewDocumentCommand{\cc}{m}
 {
  \clist_gset:Nn \g_userx_cc_names_clist { #1 }
 }

% use the variable
\NewDocumentCommand{\makecclist}{}
 {
  \clist_if_empty:NF \g_userx_cc_names_clist
   {
    \begin{tabular}{ @{} l l @{} }
    CC: & \clist_use:Nn \g_userx_cc_names_clist { \\ & }
    \end{tabular}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\cc{Dr. A Name, Mr. B Name, Dr. C Name}

\makecclist

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is totally magical.